# Selenium Java - Is there a way to make a custom environment URL?

Tags: java, selenium, url

Is there a way to make a custom environment URL for automation test cases?

E.g. now I use driver.get("https://google.com");

But if I want to use another environment I have to manually change the url in the code every time. I was wondering if there is any way to do this? Maybe some configuration/arguments.

P.S.: I am not using Maven, only TestNG.

Thank you.

Comment: You can pass in the value of the url through the testng.xml using the Parameters annotation on a test or configuration method. http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-testng-xml

Comment: read the value from a configuration file or environment variable.

Comment: Easiest way is to use properties file to store the URLs and you can read them while you run the tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom environment for any property e.g. *URL* for automating test cases by using property files. Here is a short example :

- Create a directory within your project space e.g. **config_demonstration_dir** and create a file **config.property** within and list the *urls* you want to invoke while your *Test Execution* as follows :

  ```
  DEV_URL=https://www.google.com
  UAT_URL=https://www.facebook.com
  ```
- Create a *@Test* annotated Class (using TestNG) and using the *Properties* class load the file `config.property` as follows :

  ```
  package ConfigurationDemo;

  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
  import java.util.Properties;

  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.testng.annotations.Test;

  public class UsingConfiguration 
  {

      @Test
      public void testConfig() throws Exception
      {
          File src = new File("./config_demonstration_dir/config.property");
          FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
          Properties pro = new Properties();
          pro.load(fis);
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
          driver.get(pro.getProperty("DEV_URL"));
          //or
          //driver.get(pro.getProperty("UAT_URL"));
          System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
          driver.quit();


      }
  }
  ```
- Now while you will execute the `@Test` annotated Class within `driver.get()` you can invoke either of the property **DEV_URL** or **UAT_URL**.
- Using **DEV_URL** console output is :

  ```
  Google
  PASSED: testConfig

  ===============================================
      Default test
      Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
  ===============================================


  ===============================================
  Default suite
  Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
  ===============================================
  ```
- Using **UAT_URL** console output is :

  ```
  Facebook – log in or sign up
  PASSED: testConfig

  ===============================================
      Default test
      Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
  ===============================================


  ===============================================
  Default suite
  Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
  ===============================================
  ```